# Como criar uma View para inserir múltiplas entidades

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc

Tenho uma entidade que possui entidades filhas, exemplo:
- Fornecedor (possui os dados principais do fornecedor)
- FornecedorEmails
- FornecedorTelefones
- FornecedorEnderecos
- etc...

Onde cada entidade é uma tabela do banco de dados relacionadas entre si.

No MVC criei um Model para cada entidade e ai surgiu uma dúvida.

Para Listar, vou usar apenas a entidade principal, porém para inserir um novo registro ou editar um existente, vou precisar que minha View mostre todos os campos de todas entidades.

Qual melhor solução? 
- Criar uma View para cada entidade, e de alguma forma chamar todas views na mesma página?
- ou criar uma view apenas com todas entidades?

Em ambos casos, como implemento essas soluções?

Comment: Só com isso é difícil responder, me parece que é o caso pra uma *view* apenas e não tem que chamar nenhum outra, mas depende da UI que deseja, da UX pretendida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sua view:

```
public class FornecedorViewModel 
{
    public FornecedorViewModel()
    {
        FornecedorEmails = new List<FornecedorEmailsViewModel>();
        FornecedorTelefones = new List<FornecedorTelefonesViewModel>();
        FornecedorEnderecos = new List<FornecedorEnderecosViewModel>();
    }
    //suas outras props aqui..

    public virtual IEnumerable<FornecedorEmailsViewModel> FornecedorEmails { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<FornecedorTelefonesViewModel> FornecedorTelefones { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<FornecedorEnderecosViewModel> FornecedorEnderecos { get; set; }
}
```

para a tela de listagem, caso a tela seja somente uma list de forencedores, você deverá tipar sua view da seguinte maneira:

```
@model IEnumerable<FornecedorViewModel>
```

para as telas onde precisará de somente 1 Fornecedor, porém, com seus atributos filhos, tipe conforme abaixo:

```
@model FornecedorViewModel
```

Vale ressaltar que o diferencial vai estar onde você pega os dados (No caso um repositorio). Você deverá na tela de listagem trazer somente os dados do Fornecedor, enquanto nas outras, você deverá trazer os resultados do Fornecedor e das suas classes filhas.

Para acessar as propriedades filhas de Fornecedor em sua view, basta chamar Model (com M maiusculo) e a partir dela, você navegará em qualquer entidade filha. Exemplo:

```
@Model.FornecedorEmails
```

Obs.: essa é apenas uma visão. Você pode implementar de N maneiras distintas.

Comment: muito obrigado! era isso mesmo que precisava!

Answer (score 0):

Bom, eu criaria um novo model `obterFornecedoresModel` Com as definiçoes dos outros models. Tipo    `public IEnumerable<Fornecedor> Fornecedores{ get; set; }` E assim por diante com as outras entidades.

Com isso teria só uma view, com um model, e faria todas as interações no controller. Não sei se é a melhor forma, mas acho que ajuda.